# Sharing data between multiple Angular 2 apps

Tags: angular

I build an application in Angular 2, and I need a part of the application to be opened on a second tab, so the user will be able to change data in the second tab and the data will be updated in the first tab. But I can't just open a certain router from the application in another tab, because the whole application will be loaded with that, and it's like another application, and the data will not be updated in the first tab.
So I've decided to make the second tab to be absolutely another application, and somehow to share data between those two applications and the data will be updated dynamically.
The point is, that I don't know how to share this data. I've tried to use local storage, but it doesn't work for me, because the first application does not recognize the value of the localStorage that I changed in the second application.

So what should I do? Is there any way to share data between multiple application in Angular 2? Maybe some a common service? I would also like to detect when that data is changed, if it's possible.
Does any one have any idea?

Comment: You might want to check out SignalR. Its backend is for .NET, hoping that is no problem for you.